# Can anyone share the code to access the onpremise Dynamic Nav end points

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I have a task to access the on-premise Dynamic Nav Rest API. I could not able to find any logic to access the token logic. Could please provide some code snippets to access the Endpoint URLs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend...

Web Service Walkthroughs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/web-service-walkthroughs

the first result after "googling" for "consume dynamics nav web services"